# Python, need to input csv file into a loop

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I'm going to come across as a bit of a tard.
Only just started to learn Python in the last couple of days.

Here is what i have so far

```
import os
import urllib2
from csv import DictReader

with open('Infodoc 2.txt','r') as infile:
    incsv = DictReader(infile)
    for row in incsv:
        print row['Publisher']
        DocIn = row['DocIn']
        DocOut = row['DocOut']
        WebAddy = row['WebAddy']

def moo():
    os.rename(DocIn, DocOut)
    file(DocIn, "wb").write(urllib2.urlopen(WebAddy).read())
    hosts0 = open(DocIn,"r")
    hosts1 = open(DocOut,"r")
    lines1 = hosts0.readlines()
    for i,lines2 in enumerate(hosts1):
        if lines2 != lines1[i]:
            print "line ", i, " in hosts1 is different \n"
            print lines2

moo()
```

What I am aiming for is for each line for my txt document to go through my function.
This code works once and that's it. I want it to be able to go through and pull each line and run it and then go to the next line.
I got a feeling i need to break out the rows into lines and repeat with some sort of loop?

If you could sort of point me in the right direction or give me a mini breakdown that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with where you define `moo()`.  As written, after your imports

```
with open('Infodoc 2.txt','r') as infile:
    incsv = DictReader(infile)
    for row in incsv:
        print row['Publisher']
        DocIn = row['DocIn']
        DocOut = row['DocOut']
        WebAddy = row['WebAddy']
```

runs.  After looping through all of `'Infodoc 2.txt`', `moo()` is defined

```
def moo():
    os.rename(DocIn, DocOut) #the last DocIn and DocOut from your csv file
    file(DocIn, "wb").write(urllib2.urlopen(WebAddy).read())
    hosts0 = open(DocIn,"r")
    hosts1 = open(DocOut,"r")
    lines1 = hosts0.readlines()
    for i,lines2 in enumerate(hosts1):
        if lines2 != lines1[i]:
            print "line ", i, " in hosts1 is different \n"
            print lines2
```

After that, you call `moo()`

```
moo()
```

`moo()` processes the last line (and *only* the last line) of `'Infodoc 2.txt'`, and your program ends.

So, you just have to move `moo()`'s definition to a point before you loop through your file with a slight modification (it should take `DocIn`, `DocOut`, and `WebAddy` as arguments), and call it inside your loop, like so

```
import os
import urllib2
from csv import DictReader

def moo(DocIn, DocOut, WebAddy): 
    os.rename(DocIn, DocOut)
    file(DocIn, "wb").write(urllib2.urlopen(WebAddy).read())
    hosts0 = open(DocIn,"r")
    hosts1 = open(DocOut,"r")
    lines1 = hosts0.readlines()
    for i,lines2 in enumerate(hosts1):
        if lines2 != lines1[i]:
            print "line ", i, " in hosts1 is different \n"
            print lines2

with open('Infodoc 2.txt','r') as infile:
    incsv = DictReader(infile)
    for row in incsv:
        print row['Publisher']
        DocIn = row['DocIn']
        DocOut = row['DocOut']
        WebAddy = row['WebAddy']
        moo(DocIn, DocOut, WebAddy)
```

It may not be a bad idea to add a `main()` function in case you want to reuse `moo()` down the road (i.e., import your module elsewhere).

```
def main(infodoc):
    with open(infodoc,'r') as infile:
        incsv = DictReader(infile)
        for row in incsv:
            print row['Publisher']
            DocIn = row['DocIn']
            DocOut = row['DocOut']
            WebAddy = row['WebAddy']
            moo(DocIn, DocOut, WebAddy)
```

And finally, protect it with a `if __name__ == '__main__':` so you're entire script isn't run if/when you do import it.  The final version would look like this:

```
import os
import urllib2
from csv import DictReader

def moo(DocIn, DocOut, WebAddy): 
    os.rename(DocIn, DocOut)
    file(DocIn, "wb").write(urllib2.urlopen(WebAddy).read())
    hosts0 = open(DocIn,"r")
    hosts1 = open(DocOut,"r")
    lines1 = hosts0.readlines()
    for i,lines2 in enumerate(hosts1):
        if lines2 != lines1[i]:
            print "line ", i, " in hosts1 is different \n"
            print lines2

 def main(infodoc):
     with open(infodoc,'r') as infile:
         incsv = DictReader(infile)
         for row in incsv:
             print row['Publisher']
             DocIn = row['DocIn']
             DocOut = row['DocOut']
             WebAddy = row['WebAddy']
             moo(DocIn, DocOut, WebAddy)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('Infodoc 2.txt')
```

Comment: I don't really understand whats happen with your last example. The other ones work fine. 
Every time i ad a new document for the first time ie DocIn i get IndexError: list index out of range, which is a pain if I add more then one new row to my list. I could probable create a different script to make new documents and not check but is there a reason i am getting this? Is there to much info in the page?

Comment: It means that `lines1` shorter than`hosts1` .